# Посоветуйте книгу.

Tags: c++, книги

Книга по С++. Можно и неуглубленно в тему - но чтобы было ясно и понятно написано и хорошо запоминалось. Нужны только основы - синтаксис. Описание заумных функций и крутых приёмов необязательно.

Comment: Посмотрите [эту](http://hashcode.ru/questions/35578/%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-c) тему

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и другая литература по С++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DX C++ Горнаков, Станислав

VC++ MFC и API функции Давыдов, Владимир

Очень хорошие книги у шилда

ну это так с ходу, сам только начал осваивать... очень доходчиво изложен материал.

Видел еще пару книг, но никак не могу найти электронный вариант..

ЗЫ: Сколько людей столько и мнений, начинаешь читать книгу... и понимаешь, или ты видишь фигу или ты всё схватываешь на лету... так что авторов и книги подберешь постепенно сам)

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите `Лафоре`, а вообще такие вопросы уже здесь задавались.

Comment: извиняюсь..значит не нашёл.